# Trouble deleting objects from JSON array if it matches a specific condition using PHP. Code is throwing errors

Tags: php, json

I have this json array I need to loop through and delete all objects that have a stock of 0.

JSON

```
[
  {
    "products": [
      {
        "title": "cars",
        "stock": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "bike",
        "stock": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "dog",
        "stock": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "cat",
        "stock": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So far I have this code below:

```
<?php
$str = '[{"products":[{"title":"cars","stock":0},{"title":"bike","stock":2},{"title":"dog","stock":0},{"title":"cat","stock":3}]}]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($str,true);
foreach($json_decoded as $index){
    foreach(['products'] as $product_index => $product_data){
        if($product_data['stock'] == 0){
            unset($json_decoded[$index]['products'][$product_index]);
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($json_decoded));
?>
```

Here is the run-able snippit: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5d3fb1c98c9cfba7f030c0605e138721bccc937

But I receive only errors:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'stock' in [...][...] on line 6

Warning: Illegal offset type in [...][...] on line 7
```

I am at a dead end on how to proceed, obviously there is an error with my code but I am not very familiar with how JSON array functions. I need to delete the parent of any item with a stock of zero. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' or ','` in `echo json_encode($json_decoded));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreach loop has a mistake:

```
foreach($json_decoded as $index){                                 //<---- here
    foreach(['products'] as $product_index => $product_data){     //<---- here
        if($product_data['stock'] == 0){
            unset($json_decoded[$index]['products'][$product_index]);   //<---- and here
        }
    }
}
```

It should be like:

```
foreach($json_decoded as $ind=>$data){ 
    foreach($data['products'] as $product_index => $product_data){  
        if($product_data['stock'] == 0){
            unset($json_decoded[$ind]['products'][$product_index]);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You helped me understand this immensely, thanks a ton.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to use `print_r()` at each step during debugging, it may helps you to understand what kind of data you're operating

Answer (score 0):

Try this for shorter version:

```
foreach(array_keys(array_column($json_decoded[0]["products"],"stock"),0) as $no_stock){
    unset($json_decoded[0]["products"][$no_stock]);
};
```

Demo : https://3v4l.org/817Gc